# modify .htaccess to create 301 redirects and UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm on a Mac mini running the latest version of Catalina that will run on it.

woorank.com tells me that I need to setup 301 redirects for my website as per the image below.

[image: screencap of woorank.com URL error message]

I have modified my `.htaccess` in the root of my directory of my webserver `/Library/WebServer/Documents/` in the following way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.ocetacea\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://www.ocetacea.net:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L,R]
```

to try to fix this error, but woorank.com continues to report the error.

How do I modify `.htaccess` to correct this?

And what does the `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE` error mean and how do I address it?